# Graham scan convex hull algorithm - include all points on boundary

Tags: geometry, algorithms, discrete-mathematics

I have am implementing the [Graham scan algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan) to find the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of a set of (two-dimensional) points. (My implementation is in Haskell in case anyone wants to know.) The problem is that not all of the boundary points are included. In fact, my implementation is highly sensitive to the order of the points in the input (since the input is technically a list, not a set). I am looking for some help from a mathematical perspective in order to fix the problem.

To start, let me describe how I understand the algorithm:

> *Input:* $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$.
>
> *Output:* The convex hull $H$ of $S$
>
> 1. Define the point $P$ as follows: First find the subset $Y$ of $S$ of all points $(x, y)$ such that $y$ is minimum. Then $P$ is the point in $Y$ such that $x$ is minimum.
> 2. Define $\preceq$ on $S$ as $P_1 \preceq P_2$ iff $\theta_1 \leq \theta_2$ where $(r_i, \theta_i)$ is the polar representation of the vector $\vec{PP_i}$.
> 3. Define the sequence $A = \{P_i\}$ such that $P_i \in S$ and $P_i \preceq P_{i+1}$ for each $i$.
> 4. Define $H_0 = A$. Define the subsequence $H_i=\{Q_i\}$ of $H_{i-1}$ by removing the point $P_j$ from $H_{i-1}$ such that the angle $\angle P_jP_{j+1}P_{j+2}$ makes a right-hand turn and $j$ is minimum.
> 5. Let $H=H_i$ where $H_i$ contains no angle $\angle P_jP_{j+1}P_{j+2}$ which makes a right-hand turn.

Now for a more concrete example to explain the problem:

Let $S = \{(x, y) : x, y \in \mathbb{Z}, 0 \leq x, y \leq 4\}$. (Since my implementation uses a list rather than a set, $S$ is actually a the sequence $S=\{P_i\}$ of these points in lexicographical order.) From step 1, $P = (0, 0)$. My implementation also uses a stable sort, so for $P_i, P_j \in S$, if $\theta_i = \theta_j$ (again using polar coordinates for the points), then $P_i \prec P_j$ if $i < j$. This creates a problem as I consider the points $(0, 1)$, $(0, 2)$, $(0, 3)$, and $(0, 4)$ in step 4 because they appear in the sequence $S$ in that order and they are the vertices for angles with right-handed turns when they are considered. For example, the angle formed by the points $(x, y)$, $(0, 1)$, $(0, 2)$ where $x \not=0$ is a right-handed turn.

How do I modify the ordering of step 2 so that the points on the boundary appear in the correct order to obtain straight angles as I consider them in step 4?

p.s. I have decided to state my question in mathematical terms, but if you think I would get more/better feedback from programmers, I will post it on SO instead and try to frame it in programming terms.

**Addendum:**

My implementation in Haskell keeps the points

$\{(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)\}$

as it searches for the convex hull. The remaining points to check are $\{(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)\}$, in that order. The angle formed by $(1, 4)$, $(0, 1)$, $(0, 2)$ is a right-hand turn, so$(0, 1)$ is discarded. Similarly, the points $(0, 2)$ and $(0, 3)$ are discarded. Finally, $(0, 4)$ is correctly retained. I need a way to ensure that these points are encountered in the order $(0, 4)$, $(0, 3)$, $(0, 2)$, $(0, 1)$ so that no right-hand turns will be found and all of these boundary points will be retained. This is just an example, so I need to find a general solution to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: If you want a theoretically correct algorithm, then you will probably need to handle this special case. If you want a practical one, just shake the points (add small random changes), so that no three points are collinear. Finally, there is a hybrid approach with infinitesimals (see [here](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2011/08/computing-errors-with-square-roots-of.html) for an example). BTW, if you don't need Graham, [QuickHull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickHull) is much easier and generalizes to higher dimentions.

Comment: @dtldarek "If you want a theoretically correct algorithm, then you will probably need to handle this special case." I was afraid of that. That means I need to clearly specify what the special case *is*.

Comment: @dtldarek Also, I don't understand your suggestion to "shake the points so that no three points are collinear". It is precisely certain triples of non-collinear points that cause the problem: "For example, the angle formed by the points $(x, y)$, $(0, 1)$, $(0, 2)$ where $x \not=0 is a right-handed turn$."

Comment: I think I don't understand what you want. I find the order $(0,1)$, $(0,2)$, $(0,3)$, $(0, 4)$ perfectly fine. What would be the correct order for you?

Comment: @dtldarek The problem is that when my implementation encounters those points in that order, they are each discarded because they each make a right-handed turn as the vertex of an angle starting with the *preceding* point which has been kept as part of the convex hull.

Comment: As a side note I always found it easier to implement [Andrew's monotone chain convex hull algorithm](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Monotone_Chain_Convex_Hull).

Comment: @AlexJBest Thanks for the suggestion. I am solving this as an exercise from a Haskell programming book which suggested Graham scan. I will take a look at alternative algorithms as well.

Comment: @dtldarek I added more details at the end of my question to (hopefully) explain why my implementation is sensitive to the order. Perhaps my question is more Haskell-specific than I thought.

Comment: @dtldarek fixed

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with this algorithm. This degenerate case produces a result that depends on how you sort the points when there is a tie. You get essentially the same polygon regardless of inclusion of non-corner points. Anyway, if you'd like a better sorting criterion, you can sort the points using angles from an interior point of your convex hull. One method to locate an interior point is to pick any 3 (or 4, or even more) different points that are guaranteed to be on the boundary, then form some positive linear combination.

Comment: @Tunococ Yes, the polygon is the same. The perfectionist in me wants all the points from the input set which are on the boundary of that polygon ;-)

Comment: @Tunococ Currently, ties are broken by the order in which the points appear in the input. I guess I need to find a way to explicitly break ties instead.

Comment: From the example you gave us, ordering angles from an interior points will result in no ties. Well, on second thought, the method I mentioned should always give you exactly what you need.

Comment: @Tunococ At least any ties will not occur on the boundary, which is precisely want I want to avoid. Ties in the interior should not be a problem.

Comment: @Code-Guru So I consider your problem solved then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I found after the discussion in the comments to my question is to change the ordering defined in step 2:

> Let $(r_i, \theta_i)$ be the polar representation of the vector $\vec{PP_i}$ for each $P_i \in S$. Furthermore, let $\theta_{min}=\min\{\theta_i\}$ and $\theta_{max}=\max\{\theta_i\}$. Define $\prec$ on $S$ as $P_i \prec P_j$ iff $\theta_i < \theta_j$ or ($\theta_i = \theta_j = \theta_{min}$ and $r_i < r_j$) or ($\theta_i = \theta_j = \theta_{max}$ and $r_j < r_i$).

This treats the minimum and maximum values of $\theta_i$ as special cases and (as far as I can tell) sorts the points on the boundary of the convex hull in "counter-clockwise order" so that the rest of the algorithm will now include the boundary points in the output sequence.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want all the degenerate points on the boundary of the convex hull to be included, you can find the convex hull, then test each point individually and see if it lies on an edge of the convex hull, then split edges, and insert points appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Ideally, I'd like to include the boundary points as I go. I think I've found a way to do it.